# SQL server bit type Access linked tables

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I linked my Access table containing Boolean data (yes/no) type to SQL server using SSMA. It is showing up as bit field in SQL Server.

If I go to the Object properties panel in SSMS and select "Edit Top 200 rows", I can see that the bit field is represented as True/False. However, for the same table if I do:

```
select * from table
```

The output shows that the bit field has the value 0/1 instead of true or false. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simply a display format. `bit` and `boolean` are effectively the same thing. The `bit` data type is even happy to accept the `varchar` values `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` in T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @b1 bit = 'TRUE', @b2 bit = 'FALSE';
SELECT @b1, @b2;
```

This returns `1` and `0` respectively.

Many applications (like .Net) that deal with `bit`/`boolean` data types are happy to use `0`/`FALSE` and `1/TRUE` interchangeably as well. In either circumstance their value is the same.

Comment: In my Access linked table front end the values are 0 and -1. is there a way to change it to yes/no for better redability?

Comment: In what, @Jedu, your application? You decide the display format in your application, that's part of what being a presentation layer is.